# Sum the same object of array

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [ {id:1, qty:100}, {id:2, qty:200}, {id:1, qty:100}, {id:2, qty:200} ];
```

How to sum this array become to `[ {id:1, qty:200}, {id:2, qty:400} ];`

Thx.

Comment: Please share the code you've already tried, and we'll tell you how to refine or improve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sum = [];

data.forEach(function(o) {
    var existing = sum.filter(function(i) { return i.id === o.id })[0];

    if (!existing)
        sum.push(o);
    else
        existing.qty += o.qty;
});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4496escu/)

Comment: is there a way to make this a global function that can be applied to other arrays with different key names? I tried this function mergeArray (array , mainKey, secondKey)  and then called it like this  console.log(sumit(array, array.name, array.val)); but it returnes undifined.

Answer (score 1):

With `Ramda`:

```
var f = R.compose(
    R.values(),
    R.mapObj(R.reduce(function(a,b) {return {'id': b.id, 'qty':a.qty+b.qty}}, {qty:0})),
    R.groupBy(R.prop('id'))
);

var data = [ {id:1, qty:100}, {id:2, qty:200}, {id:1, qty:100}, {id:2, qty:200} ];

console.log(f(data));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4496escu/2/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get to run this on any data, but the logic seems right. Basically this code goes through your array, and for each unique instance it will store the values into a temporary array and the write over the original array with the results.

```
var temp = [];
temp.push(data[0])
for (x = 1; x < data.length; x++){
  for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
    if (temp[i].id != data[x].id && temp[i].qty != data[x].qty ){
      temp.push[data[x]];
    }
  }
}
data = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the **functional way**, with the **.reduce()** and **.map()** method.

In my example, i've made a function to make the process more generic.

```
  var data = [ {id:1, qty:100}, {id:2, qty:200}, {id:1, qty:100}, {id:2, qty:200} ];

  function reducer(data, groupBy, reduceValue){
    //Reduce your data and initialize it with an empty object
    return [].concat.apply(data.reduce(function(hash, current){
      //If hash get current key, retrieve it and add sum property
      hash[current[groupBy]] = (hash[current[groupBy]] || 0) + current[reduceValue];
      //Return our current hash
      return hash;
    }, {})).map(function(elm){
      //Retrieve object keys
      return Object.keys(elm).map(function(key){
        //Build our object
        var obj = {};
        obj[groupBy] = +key;
        obj[reduceValue] = elm[key];
        return obj;
      });
    })[0];
  }

  console.log(reducer(data, 'id', 'qty'));
  //[ {id:1, qty:200}, {id:2, qty:400} ];
```

This function takes 3 arguments

- the data which will be reduced
- the groupBy parameter
- the key of the object to sum data

Comment: That is a great function, was looking for something like that. For those who need it but don't have the id as a numeric value they should change this line obj[groupBy] = +key --> into this :obj[groupBy] = key